# "Si l'on puis dire" ou "Si l'on puit dire"

Tags: expressions, conjugaison

La forme conjuguée *« Je puis »* existe. Cette forme ne semble pas exister à la 3<sup>e</sup> personne du singulier.

Cependant à l'oral j'entends souvent *« si l'on pui? dire »*.

La popularité ne m'aide pas à choisir la terminaison : [puis](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22si+l%27on+puis+dire%22) vs [puit](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22si+l%27on+puit+dire%22).

Est-ce que la forme *« pui »* n'existe simplement pas avec le pronom **on** ?

Ou y a-t-il une règle de conjugaison que je n'ai pas trouvée ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

« <strike>Si l'on *puis dire</strike> » est complètement contraire aux règles grammaticales du français, qui veulent que la troisième personne du singulier ait une terminaison en -t ou -e (il parle, il finit), quelquefois une autre lettre quand elle fait partie de la racine du verbe (il a, il vend), mais jamais un suffixe -s. Le suffixe -s est utilisé pour la deuxième personne du singulier et dans certains cas pour la première personne.

[Google Livres](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22si+l%27on+puis%22) ne trouve qu'une occurrence de « si l'on puis dire » (il y a quelques autres résultats qui sont des faux positifs), clairement une erreur.

« Si l'on puit dire » est conforme aux règles morphologiques de base, mais il n'est pratiquement pas utilisé : [14 occurrences sur Google Livres](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22si+l%27on+puit%22). C'est [négligeable par rapport à « si l'on peut dire »](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=si+l%27on+puit+dire%2Csi+l%27on+peut+dire&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csi%20l%27%20on%20puit%20dire%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csi%20l%27%20on%20peut%20dire%3B%2Cc0). On est dans le domaine de la [coquille, même pas la distraction](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11/prescriptivist-vs-descriptivist-prescriptif-ou-descriptif/155#155).

On pourrait penser au dico étymologique, parce que *puit* est une conjugaison obsolète du verbe pouvoir (qui survit à la première personne, essentiellement dans la tournure interrogative « puis-je »), mais [les occurrences sur Google Livres sont plutôt récentes](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=si+l%27on+puit+dire&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csi%20l%27%20on%20puit%20dire%3B%2Cc0). Il est possible que cette forme rentre à nouveau dans l'usage dans cette expression par analogie avec l'expression figée « si je puis dire », mais on en est encore loin.

Comment: Merci pour vos recherches et votre analyse !

Answer (score 4):

Si l'on recherche une expression correcte, il faut dire

> - *Si je peux dire* ou *si je puis dire*.
> - Si l'***on peut dire***.

---

***Origine des usages***

- *Peux-je* n'étant pas audible, l'usage à modifié la phonie :
- *Puis-je* est la forme interrogative, que l'on utilise parfois aussi à l'affirmatif.

*Peut-on* est la forme interrogative à la troisième personne, elle est audible et prononçable, donc *puit[-on]* n'existe pas.

Seule la première personne du singulier de ce verbe accepte deux graphies.

*Si on puit dire* est un néologisme(le correcteur orthographique en ligne signale une erreur au moment de la frappe)  ; peut-être qu'à force d'être employé (à tort) l'usage sera accepté, mais c'est à déconseiller (***faux, cf. plus bas en 2022***)

Mettre un *s* (signe de la première personne du singulier) après pui* (à la troisième personne du singulier) est une aberration... à faire hérisser les rares cheveux de nos académiciens. :)

***7 ans après***

En fait https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=si+l%27on+puit+dire&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3 l'incise *si l'on puit dire* a repris vigueur par des auteurs reconnus (https://www.google.com/search?q=si+l%27on+puit+dire&tbm=bks) bien après la fin de ma scolarité.

Comment: En fait, il semble que ce soit l'inverse : "puit" a disparu ([source](http://mamiehiou.over-blog.com/article-ne-pas-confondre-je-peux-je-puis-je-pus-je-puisse-je-pusse-puis-je-puisse-je-ou-puisse-je-109705575.html))

Comment: @Random - Si vos recherches aboutissent, je corrigerai ma réponse en conséquence.

Comment: @cl-r tout à fait. Personne n'est à l'abri d'une faute de frappe. Il est dommage que ce site ne permette pas les petites corrections sans passer par un commentaire. Attention, ce message s'autodétruira.

Comment: Effectivement ”si l'on puit dire” est en train de (ré)apparaître, mais [il reste complètement anecdotique, de l'ordre de 0,1%](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=si+l%27on+puit+dire+%2F+si+l%27on+peut+dire&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28si%20l%27%20on%20puit%20dire%20/%20si%20l%27%20on%20peut%20dire%29%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: @Random …… disparition …… qui ressemble à une longue éclipse !

Answer (score 0):

« Si l'on puit dire » existe encore : il ne s'agit pas d'une faute de frappe ou d'une coquille, plutôt je le considère une forme désuète et précieuse, un clin d’œil entre connaisseurs. Le correcteur de Google n'est pas assez cultivé pour le reconnaître. Ceci est l'avis d'une étrangère qui adore les vieilles tournures.

Comment: Ceci ne semble pas répondre à la question ! (« Est-ce que la forme « pui » n'existe simplement pas avec le prénom on ? »/ « puis vs puit »).

Comment: https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pouvoir (vers le bas de page) En incise. *Si l'on peut dire, *si je puis dire***. Synon. pour ainsi dire (v. dire1).Des êtres sonores indiscutables, remplissant tout l'espace, −tout l'abîme pourrait-on dire −entre l'explicite musical et l'explicite dramatique (Schaeffer,Rech. mus. concr., 1952, p.145). Si DeepL https://www.deepl.com/translator#fr/en/si%20l'on%20puit%20dire%0A tousse, comme moi sur *on puit dire*, il m'est arrivé de dire *si je puis dire* … je découvre que le *puit* est revenu à la mode il y a une trentaine d'année, d'où correction de ma réponse.

Comment: @Reyedy : Suite à mon commentaire ci-dessus, il ne m'est pas possible de remettre la réponse de C. Le Gall en ligne.

Comment: @Reyedy … et à la confirmation de *Gilles 'SO nous est hostile'* avec son commentaire dans ma réponse.